# htaccess RewriteBase didn't change DOCUMENT_ROOT

Tags: php, .htaccess

I tyr to rewriteBase for my root directory, yet when I echo root directory, it still shows /localhost/

anyone know how to fix this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/public

echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Comment: what kind of output you want to achieve?

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject/public

Comment: try this one 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /store [L]

Comment: nothing change, where should i place my htaccess file? im currently place in myproject/public/.htaccess

Comment: can you show us your files structure?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /myproject [L]

Comment: RewriteBase cannot modify the server's DOCUMENT_ROOT. That is configured at the server level. It would help to know what your end goal is - specific examples of what input URL you want to send from the browser, what internal path it should be rewritten to and what URL should result in the browser address bar.

Comment: i got this, now, thx a lots!